# how to check if certain image format is uploaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-extension

I have some code to check what type of file format is being uploaded. I only want to allow tiff or jpeg files, so if any other file is trying to be uploaded then display alert message

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#fuUpload").change(function () {
           var fileExtension = ['jpeg', 'tiff'];
           if ($.inArray($(this).val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase(), fileExtension) == -1) {
                alert("Only formats allowed are: " + fileExtension.join(', '));
           }
      });
 });
```

The problem is in this code it is displaying the alert even if the correct file is being uploaded. I only want the alert to display if the file is not tiff or jpeg.

Comment: Then change your if condition? I'm going to assume this is some source code you have found on the web...

Comment: @NewToJS yes but what do I need to change it to?

Comment: @NewToJS the error message doesn't appear at all now no matter what type of file I try to upload

Comment: No doubt because your condition doesn't make sense. I have put that comment in place as I haven't checked to see if your current source code is working or not. I'm showing you how to reverse the if condition from - If  something equals to something - to - if something does not equal to something.

Comment: @NewToJS ok but what do I need to do to fix my code?

Comment: I will post an answer for you now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your if condition to:

```
if(!(fileExtension.indexOf($(this).val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase()) > -1))
```

**OR**

```
if(!($.inArray($(this).val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase(),fileExtension) >-1))
```

> Demo One

```js
var fileExtension = ['jpeg', 'tiff'];
function MyFunc(e){
if(!(fileExtension.indexOf(e.split('.').pop().toLowerCase()) > -1)){
  alert('Format Not Accepted');
}else{
 alert("This Format Is Okay!");
}
}
```

```html
<button value="image.tiff" onclick="MyFunc(this.value);">Image.tiff</button>
<button value="image.gif" onclick="MyFunc(this.value);">Image.<b>gif</b></button>
<button value="image.jpeg" onclick="MyFunc(this.value);">Image.jpeg</button>
```

> Demo Two

```js
var fileExtension = ['jpeg', 'tiff'];
function MyFunc(e){
if(!($.inArray(e.split('.').pop().toLowerCase(),fileExtension) >-1)){
alert("Only formats allowed are: " + fileExtension.join(', '));
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button value="image.tiff" onclick="MyFunc(this.value);">Image.tiff</button>
<button value="image.gif" onclick="MyFunc(this.value);">Image.<b>gif</b></button>
<button value="image.jpeg" onclick="MyFunc(this.value);">Image.jpeg</button>
```

If you have any questions about the source code above please leave a comment below.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: thanks for the answer but it still doesn't work. The alert still displays if any image type is uploaded

Comment: I have expanded the answer using your own source code with a working demo. If this doesn't work for you then you must have something else going on with your source code.